# Анимация на контроллере не появляется. Objective-c

Tags: ios, ios7

На контроллере должна быть анимация построения графика. Но ее нет. Сам график присутствует. Пробовал запускать контроллер отдельно. Анимация есть. Почему нет анимации, когда я перехожу по кнопке(программно заданная) с помощью этого кода?
Как сделать ее?

```
// Creating the line chart
FSLineChart* lineChart = [[FSLineChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 500, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - -5, 176)];
lineChart.verticalGridStep = 5;
lineChart.horizontalGridStep = 9;

lineChart.labelForIndex = ^(NSUInteger item) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)item];
};

lineChart.labelForValue = ^(CGFloat value) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", value];
};

[lineChart setChartData:chartData];
return lineChart;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать animated из presentViewController (посомтреть появится ли анимация); или вызывать анимацию в viewDidAppear как посоветовали в ответе.

Comment: Не работает таким способом.

Comment: ну давайте смотреть код в 'DetailYV'

Comment: Добавил к вопросу

Comment: а где анимация? предполагаю, что она происходит в `setChartData`, можно его посмотреть? И как писали ранее, попробовать перенести генерацию из `viewDidLoad` во `viewDidAppear` если еще не пробовали

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать решить эту проблему двумя вариантами:

### 1 вариант.

Увеличить длительность анимации, задав `lineChart` время анимации через проперти `animationDuration`

### 2 вариант.

Установить `lineChart` в проперти чтобы был к нему доступ из других методов. И перенести задание данных в график `[lineChart setChartData:chartData]` в метод `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Анимация выполняется раньше, чем отображается контроллер.
так анимация работает:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t) (300 * NSEC_PER_MSEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    [self.view addSubview:[self chart1]];
    [self.view addSubview:[self chart2]];
});
```

хотя возможно, есть лучшее решение.